# Does this boiler flame look ok?

Tags: boiler, natural-gas

This is my natural gas hot water heating boiler flame.   It lights up initially with a fair bit of orange flame, and after 10 seconds or so settles into what's pictured.  I believe it mostly looks as it should, but there are several parts of the flame burning orange.  How bad is this?  I know I should clean it, which I'll do in the spring.  This doesn't need immediate attention does it?   I have a CO detector nearby, reading 0 all the time.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning the burners every few years or so is always a good idea, because loose debris accumulates on and around the burners.  This debris gets sucked into the flames, causing those intermittent yellow bursts, as seen in the picture.

But, the flames in the picture look normal otherwise.